# HTML differences from iOS 9.3.5 to most up to date iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I was tasked to create a simple page that would compare two strings to see if they matched. The scanning gun the users would use entered characters individually, and after discovering iOS hates `.focus()` for fields since the keyboard is always opened when a field is selected.

While testing on the iPad I was provided (most up to date iOS) everything worked just fine, and when we were ready to launch, we found out that the iPads the users would be using were older generations, and locked at 9.3.5.

"No problem" I thought, but I was wrong. The page is loading, but it seems that none of the JS is firing off.

I'm including my source here, which I think is well enough documented and very straight forward. I'm not incredibly versed in testing for iPads, especially any iOS, so I was hoping anyone familiar with iOS HTML/ JS gotchas could give a quick look and see if there are any red flags.

I won't lie, I love feed back, but with the time line I was originally given, the process it'self could be considered pretty janky. I'd love feed back, but understand I don't have the time to change fundamentally how this works.

Thanks!

```
    <head>

        <body type="original">

            <div>

                <center>

                    <br><br><img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo"><br>

                </center>

            </div>

            <div>

                <center>

                    <input id="promptField" value="Press clear to start scanning." type="focus" oninput ="allocateValue()">

                    <input id="serialInputOne" onclick="document.getElementById('promptField').focus();" type="text"><br>

                    <input id="serialInputTwo" onclick="document.getElementById('promptField').focus();" type="text"><br>

                    <input id="clear" onclick ="clearFields()"  type="submit" value="Clear">

                </center>

            </div>

        </body>

        <script type="text/javascript">


            function allocateValue(){
                // Timeout length (300) calibrated to how long the gun takes to register, at the moment, the longest string we handle: 8.  If we start using longer strings, setTimeout length should be adjusted accordingly.
                setTimeout(function(){
                    let clearCode = 11212001;
                    if(filterNumbers(document.getElementById('promptField').value) === undefined){
                            return false;
                    } else if (filterNumbers(document.getElementById('promptField').value) === clearCode){
                        // 11212001 is the Clear bar code output. Length is intentionally longer then our longest serial code to prevent a highly unlikely match. If we start using longer strings, Clear code should also be extended.
                        clearFields();
                    } else {
                        let serial = filterNumbers(document.getElementById('promptField').value).toString();
                        let inputOne = document.getElementById('serialInputOne').value;
                        let inputTwo = document.getElementById('serialInputTwo').value;
                        let errorCode = '*';
                        if (inputOne === "") {
                            document.getElementById('serialInputOne').value = serial;
                            document.getElementById('promptField').value = 'Scan a matching serial number.';
                            return;
                        }else if(inputTwo === "" || document.getElementById('promptField').value[0] ===errorCode) {
                            // Using "*" as a condition helps future implementations.  If any additional unique errors need to be added, have it start with the asterisk. 
                            document.getElementById('serialInputTwo').value = serial;
                            inputTwo = serial;
                            checkFields(inputOne, inputTwo);
                        }else if(inputOne === inputTwo){
                            additionalCheckResetFields();
                        }
                    }
                }, 300)
            }

            function checkFields(inputOne, inputTwo) {
                if (inputOne === inputTwo) {
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#27AE60";
                    document.getElementById('promptField').value = 'Match! A new process will automatically start when you scan again.';
                }else{
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#C9282E";
                    document.getElementById('promptField').value = '**Not a match. Either scan it\'s correct match, or Clear with the button or scan the Clear bar code.**';
                }
            }

            function additionalCheckResetFields(){
                document.getElementById('serialInputOne').value = filterNumbers(document.getElementById('promptField').value);
                document.getElementById('promptField').value = 'Scan a matching serial number.';
                document.getElementById('serialInputTwo').value = '';
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1B46A8";
            }

            function clearFields(){
                document.getElementById('promptField').value = 'Start with your first serial number.';
                document.getElementById('serialInputOne').value = '';
                document.getElementById('serialInputTwo').value = '';
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1B46A8";
                document.getElementById('promptField').focus();
            }

            function filterNumbers(field){
                // returns a array, indexing each number. Since the none of the promptField values have numbers, it will only return one number: the serial input.
                // if a promptField is ever changes where a number is involved, the serial is always located at the end of the field, thus the last index of numbers array
                // is returned automatically.
                if (!isNaN(field[field.length - 1])) {
                    let numbers = field.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
                    return numbers[(numbers.length - 1)];
                }
            }

        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

            input[type=text], select {
                padding: 10px 20px;
                margin: 30px;
                border: 6px solid #C9282E;
                border-radius: 400px;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                height: 180px;
                width: 72%;
                text-align: inherit;
                font-size: 135px;
                user-select: none;
            }

            input[type=submit] {
                width: 40%;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: #50505C;
                border: 6px solid #C9282E;
                border-radius: 20px;
                color: white;
                padding: 14px 20px;
                margin: 8px 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 25px; 
            }

            input[type=focus]{
                padding: 10px 20px;
                margin: 30px;
                background-color: #50505C;
                border: 6px solid #C9282E;
                border-radius: 20px;
                color: white;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                height: 25px;
                width: 80%;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            body[type=original]{
                background-color: #1B46A8;
            }

            img{
                height: 15%;
                width: 15%;
            }

        </style>

    </head>



</html>
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question itself - your link may change and make your question difficult to understand

Comment: @Avery Good point. I don't post here ever, so thanks for the suggestion!